# ArcGIS Pro: Points to Line will not accept point feature class

Tags: arcgis-pro, points-to-line

I'm trying to make a graphic for a presentation where multiple points are connected to a single origin (hub and spokes). I initially had over a thousand spoke end points but many of them were duplicate locations so I dissolved them and got the number down to 26. I then duplicated the hub location 25 times to get a matching number between spoke points and hub points and have values of 1 to 26 for the spoke points and corresponding values 1 to 26 for the duplicate hub points in a line field.

I want to run the points to line field to generate crow flies paths from the spoke points to the hub but the tool will not recognize my point file as an acceptable input. It recognizes the file I did the dissolve from but not it's output.

What do I need to do to make this tool run?

Comment: Most likely your created multipoint during dissolve. Points might look coincident but they are not.

Comment: Ahh...Gotcha. Okay, gonna try converting multpart to singlepart.

Comment: @ FelixP That worked. I'll check ya. Thanks!